# Spaces in variable

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am facing some problems with spaces in variables:

```
ALBUM=' -metadata album="Peregrinações Alheias"'
```

This command:

```
ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k "$ALBUM" -y $OUT
```

Returns:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -metadata album="Peregrinações Alheias"'
```

And if I take out the "" from the variable:

```
ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k $ALBUM -y $OUT
```

Returns:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Alheias"'
```

And I am sure I am missing something in the bash sintax...

---

**UPDATE:**

So it looks that the matter is not with spaces but with the "-metadata" argument...

The problem is that I have many metadata and I'd like to put them in just one variable. Like this:

`META=' -metadata album="Peregrinações" -metadata title="Passeio ao PETAR" -metadata author="Rogério Madureira" -metadata date="2012" -metadata description="Áudio de um passeio ao PETAR" -metadata comment="Áudio capturado com TACAM DR-07MKII e Foto capturada com Canon PowerShot S5IS" '`

And then:

`ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k $META -y $OUT`

Answer (score 2):

Bash interprets words in quotes as a single argument.  Try

```
ALBUM='album="Peregrinações Alheias"'
ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND \
  -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -metadata "$ALBUM" -y $OUT
```

Comment: The problem is that I have many metadata and I'd like to put them in just one variable. Like this `META=' -metadata album="Peregrinações" -metadata title="Passeio ao PETAR" -metadata author="Rogério Madureira" -metadata date="2012" -metadata description="Áudio de um passeio ao PETAR" -metadata comment="Áudio capturado com TACAM DR-07MKII e Foto capturada com Canon PowerShot S5IS" '`

Comment: `"Peregrinações Alheias"`(double-quotes are unnecessary)

Comment: Well, with or without double quotes I am getting this: `Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -metadata album=Peregrinações -metadata title=Passeio ao PETAR -metadata author=Rogério Madureira -metadata date=2012 -metadata description=Áudio de um passeio ao PETAR -metadata comment=Áudio capturado com TACAM DR-07MKII e Foto capturada com Canon PowerShot S5IS'`

Answer (score 2):

[Put your command in an array instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: +1 this is the way to go: `META=(-metadata album="Peregrinações" ...); ffmpeg ... "${META[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
ALBUM='album=Peregrinações Alheias'

ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -metadata "$ALBUM" -y $OUT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to set `ALBUM`, then Adam's answer is OK. But if you want to *optionally* set `ALBUM` then use this:

```
ALBUM="Peregrinações Alheias"
TITLE="Passeio ao PETAR"
OPTIONAL=
ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k \
     ${ALBUM:+-metadata album="$ALBUM"} \
     ${TITLE:+-metadata title="$TITLE"} \
     ${OPTIONAL:+-metadata optional="$OPTIONAL"} \
    -y $OUT
```

When not setting `ALBUM` the complete `${var:+subst}` block is omitted. Other vars are just the same of course-

Of course this scales up to several `-metadata` options *if* there is a fixed set of data you want to set.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` can do what you want...  Depending on what you have in `$R_IMG`, `$SOUND` and `$OUT`, they may need double-quote escaping, eg. `\"$SOUND\"` ....

Your `$META` (which I assume is another name for youur originally named $ALBUM) doesn't need to be laid out like this, but it surely helps (me) ... Just spaces, as in your original works just as well.

```
META='
-metadata album="Peregrinações"
-metadata title="Passeio ao PETAR"
-metadata author="Rogério Madureira"
-metadata date="2012"
-metadata description="Áudio de um passeio ao PETAR"
-metadata comment="Áudio capturado com TACAM DR-07MKII e Foto capturada com Canon PowerShot S5IS"
'; META="$(echo "$META" |sed 's|"|\\\\"|g' |tr '\n' ' ')" 

eval "ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k $META -y $OUT"
```

---

If you prefer to not use the `sed` conversion line, you simply need to change each `"` in `$META` to `\\"` as in this next example:

```
META=' -metadata album=\\"Peregrinações\\" -metadata title=\\"Passeio ao PETAR\\" -metadata author=\\"Rogério Madureira\\" -metadata date=\\"2012\\" -metadata description=\\"Áudio de um passeio ao PETAR\\" -metadata comment=\\"Áudio capturado com TACAM DR-07MKII e Foto capturada com Canon PowerShot S5IS" '
eval "ffmpeg -i $R_IMG -r 1 -b 1800 -i $SOUND -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k $META -y $OUT"
```

---

I've tested it successfully with the following `ffmpeg` encoding parameters:

```
eval "ffmpeg -i ~/input.flv -sameq -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k $META -y ~/output.mp3"
```